# „Hässlich wie eine Rolle Stacheldraht“

Tags: slang

Auf der Heute Show der letzten Woche sprach Dietmar Wischmeyer.  Hier verstehe ich aber etwas nicht ganz:

> Als die Holländer im XVII Jahrhundert die Insel Mauritius in Besitz
> nahmen, lebte da der harmlose Dodo. Der schmeckt nicht mal. Die
> Schweine haben ihn nur gekillt, weil er Scheiße aussieht, weil er hässlich wie eine Rolle
> Stacheldraht ist. [Quelle: um die Minute 7:20](https://www.zdf.de/comedy/heute-show/heute-show-vom-10-mai-2019-100.html)

Wieso eine **Rolle Stacheldraht**? Meine Suchergebnisse sind so gut wie null (daher geht es nicht um eine Mundart). Was soll denn daran lustig sein? Wieso ist eine Rolle Stacheldraht besonders hässlich, verpasse ich etwas vom Kontext?

Comment: Du verpasst nichts. Die Texter haben halt einen Vergleich gesucht, der lustig klingt, und meinten mit "häßlich wie eine Rolle Stacheldraht" einen solchen gefunden zu haben. - Übrigens würden wahrscheinlich die meisten Leute sagen, dass eine Rolle Stacheldraht in der Tat nicht besonders schön aussieht. Aber es liegt natürlich im Auge des Betrachters.

Comment: Diese Art Vergleiche ist *typisch* für Wischmeyer. Ist gilt die alte Regel, *je mehr ausgedachte Worte ein Text enthält, desto geringer die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass er gut ist.*

Comment: @c.p. Ich bin mir nicht sicher ob _eine Rolle Stacheldraht_ von allen Menschen als _hässlich_ empfunden wird. Es mag gewisse Zaunfanatiker / -fetischisten geben, die sie als wunderschön und inspirierend empfinden (look westwards). /irony off ;-D

Comment: Das schon. Hässlich sind aber verdammt viele Sachen :)

Comment: Hier sind ja schon einige vernünftige Antworten hinterlegt. Ich möchte aber noch anmerken, dass Stacheldraht sehr sehr weh tun kann. Für mich kann das also auf einer Meta-Ebene auch bedeuten "Er ist so hässlich, dass es weh tut"

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Kannst Du denn etwas anderes benennen, das von allen Menschen als häßlich empfunden wird?

Answer (score 6):

Solche Redewendungen gibt es oft und viele.
"dumm wie Brot", oder "dumm wie ein Meter Feldweg" oder was auch immer.
Auf die Nacht bezogen kenne ich auch "dumm wie die Nacht", oder etwas bildlicher "der ist so dumm, wie die Nacht dunkel".
Selbes gilt für andere meist negative Adjektive wie hässlich, ungeschickt, langsam und so weiter. Dahinter steckt oft kein wirklicher Sinn oder Vergleich.

Ich vermute vieles davon denkt sich jemand einfach während des Sprechens aus. Man nimmt ein Adjektiv und irgendeinen Gegenstand, fertig ist eine neue Redewendung.
Da ist also kein Kontext dahinter, daher gibt es auch keinen zu verstehen.

Answer (score 5):

Die Aussage ist eine [Verballhornung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verballhornung) der Redewendung

> Hässlich wie die Nacht

[mit der man ausdrückt, dass etwas extrem unansehnlich ist](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~h%C3%A4sslich%20wie%20die%20Nacht%20sein&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&suchspalte[]=rart_ou&suchspalte[]=rart_varianten_ou).

Die Verballhordnung wird gerne zu kömodiantischen/parodistischen Zwecken eingesetzt. Einen tieferen Sinn in der *Rolle Stacheldraht* zu suchen ergibt hier eher keinen Sinn (wobei es hilft, dass Stacheldraht normalerweise nicht sehr attraktiv und begrifflich negativ behaftet ist). Es soll den Zuhörer eher über den Satz stolpern lassen und wohl kurz nachdenken oder auflachen lassen.

Comment: "Begrifflich negativ behaftet", das hängt doch sehr davon ab, ob man der Ein-/Ausschließende ist, oder der Ein-/Ausgeschlossene. Oder Stacheldrahtproduzent oder Händler.

Comment: Habe nie verstanden, was an der Nacht hässlich sein soll... Da finde ich den Stacheldraht schlüssiger :)

Comment: "zu kömodiantischen/parodistischen Zwecken" - ich vermute, dass eine gewisse persönliche Vorliebe für Redewendungen bei gleichzeitiger Abneigung gegen *wortgetreue* Zitate auch ein Grund ist. Der Sprecher wendet die Redewendung in erkennbarer Form an, ohne aber das Gefühl zu haben, nur die Worte anderer nachzuplappern.

Comment: Das würde nur Sinn machen, wenn die Nacht tatsächlich hässlich wäre. Ich habe schon viele schöne Nächte erlebt, aber noch nie eine schöne Rolle Stacheldraht gesehen.

Answer (score 3):

Hierbei handelt es sich um ein Stilmittel, einen Vergleich. Man kann jedes Wort mit einem beliebigen anderen Wort vergleichen. Es ist ähnlich zu einer Metapher. Verschiedene Künstler, auch in der Musik, verwenden das andauernd. Dietmar Wischmeyer empfindet scheinbar eine Rolle Stacheldraht als hässlich.

Comment: Ich finde nicht unbedingt, dass diese banale Aussage eine neue Antwort erfordert hätte, zumal das inhaltlich ja auch schon mehr oder weniger in den anderen Antworten drinsteckt.